# Disable An Interactive TextField When Clicking On Another TextField

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm trying to make it so that when I click on one textField and clear it, I can't click on another one. I have this code in my TextFieldShouldReturn function but it does not seem to work. How can I make it so that when I click on one and clear it, the other one is disabled? Tried working out a solution.

```
if widthPer == textField {
        heightPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        widthPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        heightPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        widthPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it fixes my issue.

```
  func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if widthPer == textField {
            heightPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            widthPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        } else {
            heightPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            widthPer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        return true
    }
```